# How to solve this syntax error? (Using C)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

I started learning C programming language and I wrote popular "Hello world!" program.
but when I try to execute it, this appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\asebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\asebo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\asebo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\asebo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\asebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\asebo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\asebo\OneDrive\Počítač\codeblock\c.c", line 2
    int main() {
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

P.S: I am using VS code IDE

Comment: That error reads like you're using a Python compiler on C code.

Comment: ah. That is possible, because I was programming for cca 3 months in python.
And do you know how to change it?

Comment: I don't know this IDE but you probably have to create a C project rather than a Python project.

Comment: Follow the how-to for a C or C++ project setup [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). Note that you need a valid C compiler installed on the system (many use mingw; personally I find it more trouble that its worth and just use clang or cl from native Visual Studio. Anyway, that's where I'd start.

Comment: VSC is **NOT** an IDE, it is an editor with benefits

Comment: @rioV8 That means the VS code is not good?

Comment: Look this maybe, i think it could help you 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/getting-started-with-visual-studio-for-c-and-cpp-development/

Comment: I like VSC, VSC is good if you use it as designed, if you are a starting programmer it is best to use VS for C++ or Qt Creator

Comment: I am using it as well-experienced python programmer

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "execute it"? It makes no sense in the context of the question.

Comment: It´s not relevant yet. I have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a few Python paths in your compilation output, why?

If I were you, I'd just create a C++ console app. in VS, write it and save it as C code, give it a file name, i.e., "fileName.c" and Debug it from the VS File Menu.